# How to change font size of labeled scales in Chart.js?

Tags: javascript, charts, fonts, namespaces, chart.js

In chart.js how can I set the set the font size of the axis labels?
I tried lots of codes, but none of them worked. I use a simple bar chart.
I importing:

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js"></script>
```

The code:

```
  options: {
       scales: {
           x: {
               display: true,
               size: 30
           }
       }
    }
```

On chart.js I have read, that the namespace is : options.scales[scaleId].title but it also didnt worked, when I modify my code.
https://www.chartjs.org/docs/3.3.2/axes/labelling.html

Answer (score 3):

You have to configure it in the [`font`](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/general/fonts.html) options for the label like so:

```js
var options = {
  type: 'line',
  data: {
    labels: ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange"],
    datasets: [{
      label: '# of Votes',
      data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
      borderColor: 'pink'
    }]
  },
  options: {
    scales: {
      x: {
        ticks: {
          font: {
            size: 20
          }
        },
        title: {
          display: true,
          text: 'titleX',
          font: {
            size: 25
          }
        }
      },
      y: {
        ticks: {
          font: {
            size: 20
          }
        },
        title: {
          display: true,
          text: 'titleY',
          font: {
            size: 20
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

var ctx = document.getElementById('chartJSContainer').getContext('2d');
new Chart(ctx, options);
```

```html
<body>
  <canvas id="chartJSContainer" width="600" height="400"></canvas>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/3.5.0/chart.js"></script>
</body>
```

EDIT:
Since you want to make the ticks bigger you still need to do that with the font object but than in the ticks sub category

Comment: sorry for misunderstanding, I would like to change  the labels. these:
["Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange"]
and also on Y axis these: 2 4 6 8 ....

Comment: Those are not the axis labels but the ticks :), see updated answer